# why this is returnig 404 Not Found in next js app while using const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')?

Tags: next.js, jwt

can you guys help me I'm using next js for my app.
i have hosted my app on vercel and VPS ubantu.
here is two url 1
https://supermarks.in/api/setjwt and 2nd examapp.vercel.app/api/setjwt

i'm trying to genrate JWT wing this api route its working fine on vercel diployment but when i'm diploying on Digital Ocian VPS https://supermarks.in/api/setjwt  this url is getting error 404 Not Found.
same code is workign fine on vercel, I have checked the file path and name.

under this file i'm using this code.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
export default function handler(req, res) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ usermob: req.body.usermobile }, process.env.MYKEY, { expiresIn: '1d' });
    res.status(200).json(token);
}
```